# HTTPS not working in nginx reverse proxy (docker compose)

Tags: docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a rails app, a mysql db and I'm trying to configurate a reverse proxy server using nginx. HTTP connection goes well, but no matter what I try - the HTTPS connection won't go. The nginx server just won't listen on 443. I've tried many solutions (e.g [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443479/jwilder-nginx-proxy-not-able-to-integrate-ssl-with-nginx), [2](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/issues/317), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872591/docker-compose-with-nginx-proxy-refuses-connections-from-containers-in-the-envir)) but neither worked.

I use our own certificates rather than `letsencrypt` or some similar possibilities.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
      - /home/ssl:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /home/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_HOST=app.test
    
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    .
    .
    .
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  app:
    container_name: app
    .
    .
    .
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.test
      - VIRTUAL_PORTO=https
      - HTTPS_METHOD=redirect
      - CERT_NAME=app.test
```

running `docker exec -it proxy ls -l /etc/nginx/certs` shows certificates are mounted:

```
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 1391 Nov  8 14:36 app.test.crt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 1751 Nov  8 14:29 app.test.key
```

running `docker exec -it proxy cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
  default $http_x_forwarded_port;
  ''      $server_port;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
# Default dhparam
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem;
# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header based on $proxy_x_forwarded_proto
map $proxy_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
  default off;
  https on;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                 '"$upstream_addr"';
access_log off;
                ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
                ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
resolver 127.0.0.11;
# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
# Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        server_tokens off;
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
}
# app.test
upstream app.test {
        ## Can be connected with "test_default" network
        # app
        server 192.168.176.4:3000;
}
server {
        server_name app.test;
        listen 80 default_server;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://app.test;
        }
}
```

As you can see, no 443 clauses created. When trying to reach, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` message on chrome but nothing is recorded to neither `access.log` nor `error.log`.

Any ideas? I've spend the last three days trying to crack it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has appeared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443479/jwilder-nginx-proxy-not-able-to-integrate-ssl-with-nginx), needed to add `CERT_NAME` to the `proxy` environment and mount the certificates directory to the app as well:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
      - /home/ssl:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /home/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_HOST=app.test
      - CERT_NAME=app.test
    
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    .
    .
    .
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  app:
    container_name: app
    .
    .
    .
    volumes:
      .
      .
      .
      - /home/ssl:/etc/ssl/certs:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.test
      - CERT_NAME=app.test
```